# nest js controller test use service dependency instead of the mock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nestjs

I'm new in using nest js, and am anout to do some tests.
i have  a room controller :

```
@Controller('rooms')
export class RoomController {
  constructor(private readonly roomService: RoomService) {}


  @Get()
  async findAll(): Promise<ReadRoomDto[]> {
    return await this.roomService.findAll();
  }
}
```

and here a room service

```
@Injectable()
export class RoomService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Room.name) private readonly roomModel: RoomModel,

  ) {}

  async findAll():Promise<ReadRoomDto[]> {
    return await this.roomModel.find();
  }

 
}
```

and the room model takes the following shape :

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Model, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { Building } from 'src/modules/building/models/building.model';
import { Floor } from 'src/modules/floor/entities/floor.entity';
import { Organization } from 'src/modules/organization/models/organization.model';
import { Property } from 'src/modules/property/models/property.model';

interface RoomAttrs {
  name: string;
  floor?: string;
  building?: string;
  organization?: string;
  properties?: string[];
}

export interface RoomModel extends Model<Room> {
  build(attrs: RoomAttrs): Room;
}

@Schema()
export class Room extends Document {
  @Prop()
  name: String;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: false, ref: Floor.name })
  floor: String;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: false, ref: Building.name })
  building: String;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: false, ref: Organization.name })
  organization: String;

  @Prop([{ type: String, required: false, ref: Property.name }])
  properties: String[];
}

export const RoomSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Room);

RoomSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (doc, ret) => {
    ret.id = doc._id;
    delete ret._id;
  },
});

RoomSchema.statics.build = function (attrs: RoomAttrs) {
  return new this(attrs);
};
```

when i do some test on on room controller :

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { RoomController } from '../controllers/room.controller';
import { RoomStub } from './stubs/room.stub';
import { RoomService } from '../services/room.service';


const mockRoomService = {
  findAll: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([RoomStub()]),

};

describe('RoomController', () => {
  let roomController: RoomController;
  //let roomService :RoomService

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [RoomController],
      providers: [{provide:RoomService,useValue:mockRoomService}],
      
    }).compile();
    roomController = module.get<RoomController>(RoomController);
    //roomService = module.get<RoomService>(RoomService)
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(roomController).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

i always get the error :
   `Cannot find module 'src/modules/building/models/building.model' from 'modules/room/models/room.model.ts'`
it seems like the controller doesn't use the mocked service, and use the original room service.
what seems the problem because i used every method of creating the a mock for service to avoid external dependencies injections.

i tried every injection method with mock, with original injection , but i always get a kind of using the original service

Comment: this this related with using absolute paths in jest? see https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/lmnsdtce3y-import-absolute-paths-in-typescript-jest-tests

Answer (score 0):

*Jest* doesn't understand how to resolve the absolute import (`src/modules/building/models/building.model`). You need to add the [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) jest configuration so it knows how to resolve `src/*` relative the the `rootDir` that Jest *is* aware of. Usually something like

```json
{
  ...
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^src/(.*)$": ["<rootDir>/$1"]
  }
}
```

Is what you're looking for